# Assign the value in the next row if condition is met

Tags: r, data-wrangling

This is the data that I have

```
       structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), columnA = c("2011/01/01", 
"2013/01/01", "2014/01/01", "2015/01/01", "2015/01/10"), columnB = c("NA", 
"2013/01/01", "2013/01/02", "2014/01/01", "NA")), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

and this is what I want

```
  structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), A = c("2011/01/01", "2013/01/01", 
"2014/01/01", "2015/01/01", "2015/01/10"), B = c("NA", "2013/01/02", 
"NA", "2014/01/01", "NA")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Basically, i want if the values in columnA and columnB are equal, then bring up the value from row -1 in the same column and insert an NA in place of the value going up the column.
I tried this

```
`library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(columnB = case_when(is.na(columnB) ~ NA_character_,
                             columnA == columnB ~ lead(columnB))) %>%
  ungroup

`
```

the problem is that it convert all other values in columnB to NA as well. I want where the values in A and B are not equal to remain the same and not converted to NAs.

Comment: Why is the expected output row 4 `2015/01/01` and not `NA`? The next row down is NA.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, that should be NA then as well.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description, we can use `lead`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   mutate(columnB = case_when(is.na(columnB) ~ NA_character_,
                     columnA == columnB ~ lead(columnB))) %>%
   ungroup
```

Comment: @kamrankhan change the `NA_character_` to `NA_real_` or `NA_integer_`

Comment: One issue is that it convert all other values in columnB to NAs. I have other dates where the dates in column A and B are not the same and I want them to stay as they are.

Answer (score 0):

```
aa = structure(list(
id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
columnA = c(
"2011/01/01",
"2013/01/01",
"2014/01/01",
"2015/01/01",
"2015/01/10"
),
columnB = c("NA",
          "2013/01/01", "2013/01/02", "2015/01/01", "NA")
),
row.names = c(NA,
          5L),
class = "data.frame")

bb=aa

for (i in 1:5){
 if (aa[i,2]==aa[i,3]){
bb[i,3]=bb[i+1,3] 
bb[i+1,3]="NA"
}
}
```